# What can we do about a section of plaster that has fallen off the wall?

Tags: plaster

We have an old style terraced house which normally has a breast wall which accounts for the chimney; either side of this are two alcoves that are set back perhaps half a foot. The dimensions of these alcoves are about 1.5ft wide by 10ft tall.

In one half of our room, these alcoves have been bordered up to provide a surface that's level with the breast wall. This was fully wallpapered.

As we've been stripping the wallpaper off this wall, the plaster layer on one of these alcoves has crumbled off leaving us with bare plasterboard underneath. This is about 1mm deep. What can be done in this situation?

Comment: A picture would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the plasterboard is still sound, you should be able to re-skim the board with finish plaster to restore the surface to level with the breast wall (or get a plasterer in to do it if that's not where your DIY skills lie).

Comment: Yeah, the plasterboard is fine. A couple of plasterers that we've spoken to have told us that we need to get the full wall replastered. For reference, the wall itself is about 10ft long, and the damaged section accounts for just 1.5ft - is this the case, or is that just wishful upselling?

Comment: For what little extra work is involved, it might be worthwhile having the full wall skimmed anyway - especially if you're getting someone in to do it. If you had it skimmed just up to repair the damage, you will likely see a join where the two areas meet. A plasterer will have 10 ft of wall skimmed in next to no time and will probably end up sat waiting for it to firm up before putting the second skim on.